# Rails 4: can't see errors on the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a rails app ( Rails 4), In the browser all I get is:

> 500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this
>   website...

even if i run :

> rails server -e development

I can't get errors displayed on the browser.
someone can help?

Thank you!

Comment: If your application is in production mode then give `tail -f log/production.log` to view the errors in the log file.

Comment: No, my app is not in prod :/, I just run -rails new app, then some codding, then rails server -e development , that s all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to come frome Rails. The default 500 message in Rails is "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." It looks like it is generated by something else.

Comment: Yeah! I agree with @DanielRikowski. May be it is due to server is not properly run.Check once again.

Comment: rails server WEBrick starts correctly :/ I can see my app errors print in the console but not on the browser

Comment: Do you actually have a view to render the errors?

Comment: yes I have views, when i visit the page, it seems like rails consider me like a visitor on a prod app !

Comment: Check if `config.consider_all_requests_local` is set in `config/environments/development.rb` It should be set to true on development and to false on production.

Comment: that didn't slove the problem :(